# Solving a quadratic convex optimization problem

Tags: optimization

The optimization problem that I am solving is of the form
min ||x||^2  (square of l-2 norm of x)
such that Mx <= b. Here x is a d-dimensional vector, M is the transpose of a d-dimensional vector and b is a scalar.
I started this by writing the lagrangian for this which is 2x+(M^T)*lambda = 0,
but after applying the complementary slackness condition, I am stuck and unable to solve this further.

Comment: Use a Quadratic Programming solver. Or, don't square the norm in the objective function, and use an SOCP solver (many "QP" solvers also do SOCP).

Comment: Please see this [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question)